# How to find the second derivative in R and while using newton's method with numerical derivation

Tags: r, derivative, newtons-method, gamma-distribution

The log-likelihood of the gamma distribution with scale parameter 1 can be written as:

`(α−1)s−nlogΓ(α)`
where alpha is the shape parameter and `s=∑logXi` is the sufficient statistic.

Randomly draw a sample of n = 30 with a shape parameter of alpha = 4.5. Using `newton_search` and `make_derivative`, find the maximum likelihood estimate of alpha. Use the moment estimator of alpha, i.e., mean of x as the initial guess. The log-likelihood function in R is:

```
x <- rgamma(n=30, shape=4.5)
gllik <- function() {
  s <- sum(log(x))
  n <- length(x)
  function(a) {
    (a - 1) * s - n * lgamma(a)
    }
}
```

I have created the make_derivative function as follows:

```
make_derivative <- function(f, h) {
  (f(x + h) - f(x - h)) / (2*h)
}
```

I also have created a `newton_search` function that incorporates the `make_derivative` function; However, I need to use `newton_search` on the second derivative of the log-likelihood function and I'm not sure how to fix the following code in order for it to do that:

```
newton_search2 <- function(f, h, guess, conv=0.001) {
    set.seed(2)  
    y0 <- guess
    N = 1000
    i <- 1; y1 <- y0
    p <- numeric(N)
  while (i <= N) {
    make_derivative <- function(f, h) {
  (f(y0 + h) - f(y0 - h)) / (2*h)
    }
    y1 <- (y0 - (f(y0)/make_derivative(f, h)))
    p[i] <- y1
    i <- i + 1
    if (abs(y1 - y0) < conv) break
    y0 <- y1
  }
  return (p[(i-1)])
}
```

Hint: You must apply `newton_search` to the first and second derivatives (derived numerically using `make_derivative`) of the log-likelihood. Your answer should be near 4.5.

when I run `newton_search2(gllik(), 0.0001, mean(x), conv = 0.001)`, I get double what the answer should be.

Comment: When I run newton_search2(gllik(), 0.0001, mean(x), conv = 0.001) I get double of what the answer should be. I should get about 4.5, but I get about 9.2. I'm not sure where my code has gone wrong.

Comment: You show no evidence that you have read and made an effort to correct the problems that RHertel has identified. It was also puzzling that the likelihood function had no data argument.

Comment: The likelihood equation was given to me like that. I don't think I'm supposed to change that function.

Comment: Also the derivative function had the requirement of a function closure that remembers f and h

Answer (score 0):

I re-wrote the code and it works perfectly now (even better than what I had originally wrote). Thanks to all who helped. :-)

```
newton_search <- function(f, df, guess, conv=0.001) {
    set.seed(1)
    y0 <- guess
    N = 100
    i <- 1; y1 <- y0
    p <- numeric(N)
  while (i <= N) {
    y1 <- (y0 - (f(y0)/df(y0)))
    p[i] <- y1
    i <- i + 1
    if (abs(y1 - y0) < conv) break
    y0 <- y1
  }
  return (p[(i-1)])
}

make_derivative <- function(f, h) {
  function(x){(f(x + h) - f(x - h)) / (2*h)
  }
}

df1 <- make_derivative(gllik(), 0.0001)
df2 <- make_derivative(df1, 0.0001)
newton_search(df1, df2, mean(x), conv = 0.001)
```

Comment: Nice. But don't forget to check that what you found is a maximum. I.e. plug the solution found in `df1` and `df2` and check the sign of `df2(solution)`.